# how to use an integer as a key in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the follwing code I wanted to use integers as keys in a dict:

```
import itertools  
N = {}
for a,b,c,d in itertools.product(range(100), repeat=4):
    x = a*a + c*c
    y = a*b + c*d
    z = b*b + d*d
    s = x + y + y + z
    N[s] += 1 
print N
```

I get a `KeyError: 0` at `N[s] += 1`. Why is it so? The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) says that

> strings and numbers can always be keys

The [wiki gives an explanation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError) on `KeyError`:

> Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using
>   the format `a = adict[key]`) and the key is not in the dictionary.

What I want to do is to build a dict with yet-unknown keys (they are computed on the fly) and keep a counter for them. I have done that in the past (with strings as keys) so what did I did wrong this time? (I know - this must be super obvious but after some time glaring at this complicated code I need help :))

Comment: Your key is not defined so you get an error.  (you can't add 1 to something that doesn't exist).  You probably want to use `Counter`, `from collections import Counter; N = Counter()`

Comment: Thanks - I was focusing on the existence of the key and not the value.

Comment: As a side question to the ones used to StackOverflow philosophy: why such a question would be downvoted? (I understand the concept of downvotes, I am wondering why the question would not be a fit)

Comment: Your question is fine.  You provided actual code, listed the error you received and made an attempt and deciphering the error.  If people don't like your question they should leave a comment as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first iteration, `N` is empty, however you are attempting to access `N[0]`

You can fix this particular problem with

```
if s in N:
    N[s] += 1
else:
    N[s] = 0 # or 1 or whatever
```

But as @monkut says in the comments you should use a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Thanks - I did not know Counter, it indeed simplifies the code.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict
N = defaultdict(int)
for a,b,c,d in itertools.product(range(100), repeat=4):
    x = a*a + c*c
    y = a*b + c*d
    z = b*b + d*d
    s = x + y + y + z
    N[s] += 1 
print N

# answer is too long to include here
```

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` is best because it has methods to analyze the results, but you can also use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
N = defaultdict(int)
```

If a key is not present the value will be initialized to the default for `int`, which is zero.